# using #define to substitute in a continuous string

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to write a Macro for certain read/write functions. The functions are in the form

```
k_target_socket.write8(address,val);
```

When I tried `#define Wx(add,val) k_target_socket.writex(address,val)` I got   `W8(0x100,0x120);` for   `W8(0x100,0x120);` then I replace the macro with  `#define W(x,add,val`) & then got `k_target_socket.writex(0x100,0x120);` Is there a way to substitute for `x` in the above two examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is token pasting. try the following:

```
#define W(x,ad,val) k_target_socket.write##x(ad,val)
```

The `##` will paste the `x` with the function name.

More details [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)

Comment: Thanks that works is there any similar way for Wx(ad,val) cause token pasting didn't work there.

Comment: these preprocessor directives may be compiler specific. which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using  gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: That's the same version I am using and GCC supports this. What error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error but the macro doesn't work #define Wx(ad,val) k_target_socket.write##x(ad,val) when used for W8(10,8) doesn't expand and is still W8(10,8). Just in case your are not clear your answer works for the other macro I've mentioned.

Comment: you cannot use like `Wx`, `x` should be a parameter to be passed.